# Russian equivalents of the colloquial "What's the hold-up?"

Tags: выражения

The colloquial expression "What's the hold-up?" comes in handy when someone is dawdling, testing your patience. In conversation, there are times when I feel the urge to shout its equivalent expression in Russian. Can I say something like:

> Сюда! Скорее! Чего ты там возишься?!

I'm not sure if the register fits, for one thing. I suppose there is more than one way to express this idea, but what are some commonly used, idiomatic ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**возишься** is indeed slightly derogatory and so impolite

some neutral equivalents are **За чем дело стало?** which is somewhat uptight, the simple **Ты чего там (застрял/а)?** **Ну ты где (застрял/а)?** and the slangy **Ну ты чего тормозишь?**

Answer (score 3):

In Russian, any equivalents of the phrase **"What's the hold-up"** are not rhetorical questions, so it is very likely that in response you will hear a long explanation of *"what's the hold-up"*.

So if you need acceleration, rather than explanation, it is better to use some imperative form, for example **"Не тормози! Давай скорее!"** or **"Не тяни резину, давай быстрее!"**.

Answer (score 1):

Since 'hold-up' is quite neutral (meaning 'delay') it seems to me you need more or less neutral register here. My guess is "Что так долго? Почему так долго?", preferably said so that to sound neutral, not rude. Other emotional expressions wouldn't sound neutral.